# Opening up most recent file automatically when vim is started without command line arguments

Tags: command-line, autocmd

I have found myself falling into a workflow where I'm often starting vim by running `$ vim` and then opening up the most recent file once inside.

I was wondering how to detect:

- when vim is launched
- which files it was launched with

so that in the case when no files are specified, I can run a custom command (such as opening the most recent file).

Answer (score 3):

You could start with something like this:

```
function MyVimEnter()
    if argc() != 0
        return
    endif

    if exists("v:oldfiles[0]") && filereadable(expand(v:oldfiles[0]))
        execute "e " . v:oldfiles[0]
    endif
endfunction

" The 'nested' before call allows nested autocmds, important for
" syntax detection etc.
autocmd VimEnter * nested call MyVimEnter()
```

Whenever Vim is started and finished setup, the function `MyVimEnter` is called. This checks if files where given on the command line. If yes, it returns immediately. If no, it loads the last file you edited.

Comment: Thanks. I actually had figured it out independently. One thing that might be useful for other users is that for some reason, calling `edit` (`e` here) from the `VimEnter` handler doesn't trigger all the other handlers you would want. (Syntax highlighting, for instance, doesn't work). My work-around was to use a 0-second timeout: `call timer_start(0, {tid -> DoRestore()})`, where `DoRestore` is the function to conditionally `edit` the most recent file.

Comment: @Tac-Tics Updated. Added `nested` to allow nested `autocmd`.